# android update custom view

Tags: android, view

Hello I am new programmer and I have a custom view in my app that i try to make to redraw itself after i give him new data i tried using invalidate but it seem to not work I'm not sure if the problem is the way i update the data or the way i try to make the view redraw itself. any help will be appreciated.

view:

```
public class BlackJackView extends View {
private PlayerView playerView, computerView;
private BlackJackGame game;
private Context contex;


public void setPlayer(BlackJackPlayer player) {
    playerView = new PlayerView(contex, player);
}

public void setComputer(BlackJackPlayer computer) {
    computerView = new PlayerView(contex, computer);
}

public BlackJackView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public BlackJackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public BlackJackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}


private void init(Context context) {
    this.contex = context;
    game = new BlackJackGame();
    playerView = new PlayerView(contex, game.getPlayer());
    computerView = new PlayerView(contex, game.getComputer());

}

public void init(BlackJackGame game) {
    this.game = new BlackJackGame(game.getPlayer().getName(),game.getPlayer().getMoney());
    playerView = new PlayerView(contex, game.getPlayer());
    computerView = new PlayerView(contex, game.getComputer());
    this.invalidate();
}



@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        playerView.onDraw(canvas);
        computerView.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

activity:

```
public class BlackJackActivity extends Activity {
private UsersDataSource dataSource;
private List<User> values;
private BlackJackView view;
private BlackJackGame game;
private int userID;
private int playerMoney;
private String playerName;


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    game = new BlackJackGame();
    view = new BlackJackView(this);
    view.setPlayer(game.getPlayer());


    setContentView(R.layout.black_jack_activity);
    GetId(savedInstanceState);
    GetPlayerData();
    view = (BlackJackView) findViewById(R.id.blackJackView);
    view.init(game);

}

private void GetId(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            userID = -1;
        } else {
            userID = extras.getInt("ID");
        }
    } else {
        userID = (int) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("ID");
    }
}

private void GetPlayerData() {

    //data base open
    dataSource = new UsersDataSource(this);
    dataSource.open();
    //get list of database
    values = dataSource.getAllUsers();
    playerName = values.get(userID).getUsername();
    playerMoney = (int) values.get(userID).getTokens();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    dataSource.open();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    dataSource.close();
    super.onPause();
}
```

}